# GNOME: Use WinKey (Super_L) as a main menu toggle

Tags: gnome, keyboard

I know how to set <kbd>Super_L</kbd> (WinKey) button
to open the Menu.

```
gconftool-2 --set /apps/metacity/global_keybindings/panel_main_menu --type string "Super_L"
```

Currently, in order to close that menu, I am having to mouse click outside the menu area. I need to use the <kbd>Super_L</kbd> as a toggle button—pressing one time would open and pressing second time would close.

So what I need now is to be able to close it when pressing it second time?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Edit) After having re-read the post and doing a bit more research into the subject, I found out my suggestion is a bit... stupid. But, I'll leave it here in case anyone finds inspiration from it in a similar venture.

Try writing as small script called toggle.sh, put it somewhere.

```
if `panel_is_open`
    close_panel
else
    open_panel
```

or

```
if [ `cat panel` == "on" ]; then
    close_panel
    echo 'off' > panel
else
    open_panel
    echo 'on' > panel
fi
```

Something along those lines
Then after `--set` use `/path/to/toggle.sh`