# LXDE use WinKey to open AND close main menu (LXPANEL)

Tags: lxde

I was able to set <kbd>Winkey</kbd> to open the menu. But I expect that pressing it again would close the menu which is not happening.

This issue is almost the same as this:
[GNOME: Use WinKey (Super_L) as a main menu toggle](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/21075/gnome-use-winkey-super-l-as-a-main-menu-toggle)

except this is for *LXDE* and not *GNOME*.